# Bash Regex match is case insensitive

Tags: regex, bash

Trying to match a string to only contain lowercase, digit or hypen (-). I had some problems with it and tried to debug my regex. Meanwhile I found that the following matches, even though it shouldn't:

```
$ if [[ "ABC" =~ ^[a-z]+$ ]]; then echo matched; fi
> matched
$ if [[ "ABC" =~ ^[[:lower:]]+$ ]]; then echo matched; fi
> matched

$ if [[ "abc" =~ ^[a-z]+$ ]]; then echo matched; fi
> matched
$ if [[ "abc" =~ ^[[:lower:]]+$ ]]; then echo matched; fi
> matched

$ echo $LC_CTYPE
> en_US.utf8
```

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8
LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.utf8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=de_DE.utf8
LC_NAME=en_US.utf8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.utf8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

$ echo $LC_COLLATE # Gives empty line

$ shopt nocasematch
off
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with glibc version 2.27-3ubuntu1
So I'm kinda lost here. Why does this match?

Comment: Doesn't reproduce at https://ideone.com/slwOKP, btw.

Comment: My `LC_COLLATE` was empty. But setting it to `en_US.utf8` didn't help either.

Comment: One point of note: bash doesn't have its own regex implementation; it uses the one provided by your local operating system's libc. So... what _is_ your local operating system? If it's using a separately-built libc (like glibc), which version of _that_ is in use?

Comment: Can you try `export LANG=en_US.utf8` ?

Comment: Using `export LANG=en_US.utf8` still matches the uppercase string.

Comment: It is very unlikely but have you done anything that might break your locale? Because as far as I know this has nothing to do with bash

Comment: @Teharez : I consider it highly unlikely that the issue is locale related, because `[[ "ABC" =~ ^[a-z]+$ ]]` also does not work, and even the character range `a-z` **can** depend on the character set (think EBCDIC as an example), I don't think that you have a setup wher `a-z` also includes the upper case characters. But just for the safe side: How are `[[ "ABC" =~ ^[abc]+$ ]]`,  `[[ "A" =~ ^[a]$ ]]` and  `[[ "A" =~ ^a$ ]]` behaving on your system?

Comment: @Teharez : But one more idea: What happens if you do a i.e. `export LC_ALL=C`? I don't think it should matter, but I'm still surprised that this variable is empty in your environment.

Comment: @Teharez : Could you also try setting  `shopt -s globasciiranges`? It _should_ not be related to your case, because you are doing regex matching, not globbing, but your case is unusual enought that you may want to try even such obscure attempts.

Comment: @user1934428 All three regexes are a match. Even after exporting 'LC_ALL=C'; LANG=en_US.utf8' and setting 'globasciiranges' and 'nocasematch'.  Currently doing some more testing. Definitely something to do with my bash options. Will continue checking

Comment: @Teharez: Just to make sure that this oddity **only** effects character classes, does at least `[[ "A" =~ a+ ]]` fail to produce a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it. The reason was that `nocaseglob` was set.

Also dug a bit into the source code:

`nocaseglob` is defined in [./builtins/shopt.def](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/shopt.def?id=9e49d343e3cd7e20dad1b86ebfb764e8027596a7#n229) which sets the internal variable `glob_ignore_case`.

This one in return is used in [./lib/sh/shmatch.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/shmatch.c?id=9e49d343e3cd7e20dad1b86ebfb764e8027596a7#n67) in the if-statement `if (glob_ignore_case || match_ignore_case)` which determines if the flag `REG_ICASE` should be set for the call to [`regcomp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp).

But according to the [documentation on shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) *nocaseglob* only determines if filenames are match case-insensitiv, while I expected *nocasematch* to be responsible for regex-matching:

**nocaseglob**: If set, Bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive fashion when performing filename expansion.

**nocasematch**: If set, Bash matches patterns in a case-insensitive fashion when performing matching while executing case or [[ conditional commands, when performing pattern substitution word expansions, or when filtering possible completions as part of programmable completion.

---

Tracked to at least bash-3.0 which introduced the file `shmatch.c` to the current master version 5.0.17(2)-release. Fixed in devel branch 5.1.0(3)-alpha by commit [aa99ef520](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/lib/sh/shmatch.c?id=aa99ef520f943369c826b02f3398fa8eab7bfdfb) with the [changelog](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/CWRU/CWRU.chlog?id=aa99ef520f943369c826b02f3398fa8eab7bfdfb)

lib/sh/shmatch.c
    - sh_regmatch: implement a suggestion from Grisha Levit
       and don't allow nocaseglob to enable case-insensitive regexp matching. It hasn't been documented that way
      in years

Comment: Great that you found an explanation, although it can not be backed up by the _man_ page. `nocaseglob` should only affect filename expansion, and `nocasematch` should affect only matching to the right of a `=` or `==`, but not  `=~`. Even more bizarre, today (after rebooting), my bash not only shows suddenly the same problem as yours, although _nocaseglob_ and _nocasematch_ **are** off. The same happens with zsh (which also has regexp matching). However I **could** revert this behaviour to the 'expected' one by setting `export LC_ALL=C`, which indeed affects the way character ranges are built.

Comment: I also would like to point out, that (with `LC_ALL` left empty), matching really occurs only at character **ranges**, while i.e. `[[ "ABC" =~ ^[abc]+$ ]] && echo true` does not show a match (as you said in your comment that it does on your system). This behaviour too is not affected by nocaseglob/nocasematch on my platform.

Comment: @user1934428 mh interesting. Regarding your comment about the man page: As I've written in the last paragraph it seems like this behavior was undocumented and is removed in the devel branch.
I also build my current version from the source code, with the fix in commit  [aa99ef520](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/lib/sh/shmatch.c?id=aa99ef520f943369c826b02f3398fa8eab7bfdfb) applied and the matching was then as expected. So it seems while LC_ALL can also affect regex matching, my issue was the problem mentioned in my answer.

Comment: `LC_ALL` affects the ordering, how to order the characters. For instance, if it is set to German or English, the order is like in the phone book (where `a` and `A` is treated equal). Collating occurs in regular expressions **and** in filename expansion, if a character range is specified. Hence the effect should apply to both, and it should NOT effect character classes such as `[[:lower:]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `shopt -u nocasematch` and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm guessing (the pre-edit form of) this answer was meant for zsh or another non-bash shell. In bash, the closest thing is `nocasematch`, and it's a `shopt` option, not a `set` one.

Comment: you're right, sorry, been in zsh land too long.  See edited answer above.

Comment: No this didn't help either

Comment: paste the output of `shopt`- I'm not sure what it could be besides locale or the `nocasematch` option, but can have a look.